# adding len() in for range loop python do not work

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I've tried two ways of for loops.

One worked out, but the other didn't.

```
# 1.

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1") # w/ heading 'urls'

while True:
  for url in df["urls"]:
  driver.get(url)

# it worked but keeps loading the page even after the very last page


# 2.

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")

while True:
  for url in range len(df["urls"]):
  driver.get(url)

# I tried to add len() to recover the disadvantage of the first try, but it never worked out 
and said 'series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I'd like to know how to load the pages just as much as the numbers the csv file contains

I'll be appreciated if you give some helpful tips

thank you

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors. Fix your code first.

Comment: `while True:` will not stop without `break`, `return` or an exception.

Comment: what is the type of the `driver.get` argument?

Answer (score 1):

### Code:-

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")
for url in df["urls"]:
  driver.get(url)
```